# What is the [what-is] tag for?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tags

[what-is](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/what-is) seems like the very definition of a meta tag.

Should we whack it?

Comment: [what-is love](https://twitter.com/nigelbabu/status/260416648698277888) ;)

Comment: I'm guessing it's a "oh-look-another-text-field-let's-reiterate-the-title" tag.

Comment: Not a close relative of the [`whois` tag](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/whois)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

as requested

Answer (score 3):

I say we...

## Burninate IT!!!

[image]

And then:

## Smash IT!!!!

[image]

## INTO OBLIVION!!!!

Comment: Could have sworn I've seen that text and set of graphics before on here :P

Comment: @Luke Once in a few millenia... these two come out together and form an alliance against the forces of evil.